# How to flush the DNS cache of Safari on macOS Mojave without restarting the system?

Tags: network, safari, dns

I've experimenting with configuring `dnsmasq` on macOS for Apache vhosts instead of creating entries in `/etc/resolver/<domain>` for each domain. In my case, I configured `dnsmasq` to resolve `.dev` to `localhost`.

Since Safari had previously visited `foo.dev`, it kept requesting that page, although `dig` resolved `foo.dev` to `localhost`.

It didn't help to clear Safari's web cache and flush the system's DNS cache:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

It was first after a reboot that Safari properly visited the `localhost` instance of `foo.dev` (vhost).

So, is Safari mantaining its own DNS cache - and if so, how can it be flushed without restarting the system?

Answer (score 22):

1. To clean DNS cache on macOS, the following command should be used. (commands used to clean caches seems to be different on different version of macOS)

   ```sh
   sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
   ```
2. Clean the DNS cache in Safari. Open Safari, Preferences -> Advanced. Check "Show develop menu in menu bar". Then go to menu bar, Develop -> Empty Caches. The shortcut is ⌥⌘E. (Restart of Safari may be needed)

References

- [Flush cache of DNS on macOS Sierra & High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303119/269354)

Comment: thank you. Can you explain why `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` works, and where it's documented?

Comment: @Shuzheng https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303119/269354

Comment: Any way without restarting anything including the browser?