# Where is `lookupd`?

Tags: monterey, macos

I am using macOS Monterey and I wanted to run `lookupd` (to flush my DNS cache, based on [this](https://www.infomaniak.com/de/support/faq/1041/dns-cache-ihres-computers-loschen)
recommendation which says that I need to run `lookupd -flushcache`, but I don't know which directory `lookupd` is in, and, not surprisingly, it is not in my PATH.

I already tried a `find` over `/bin`,  `/sbin` and `/System`, but nothing comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I do `man lookupd`, I get the man page for `dscacheutil`, which says:

> dscacheutil does various operations against the Directory Service
> cache including gathering statistics, initiating
> lookups, inspection, cache flush, etc.  This tool replaces most of the functionality of the lookupd tool previously
> available in the OS.

So it seems clear that `lookupd` has been replaced by `dscacheutil`.

[Flushing the DNS cache is a bit of a chore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303119/5472), though.

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder;sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper;sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

Most people don’t have LDAP, so the `dscacheutil` is not needed for most people, but flushing an empty cache just wastes a bit of time and has no effect.

Comment: lookupd was removed in Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), which came out way back in 2009. The advice linked in the question is *OLD*.